# Initial page load empty - create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I have an app which just loads a blank page on start up, yet refreshing the page causes it to load correctly.

This is what I'm trying:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './Assets/css/app.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

window.processIntent = intent => {
    ...cordova stuff
};

window.setupAltIntent = () => {
    ...cordova stuff
};

function startApp() {
    window.intentUrlToPrint = '';
    window.setupAltIntent();

    ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}

if (!window.cordova) {
    startApp();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', startApp, false);
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppActivity from './Views/activity/AppActivity';
import Header from './Components/header';
import AppRouter from './AppRouter';

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        if (navigator.splashscreen) {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Header />
                    <AppRouter />
                </div>
                <AppActivity />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**AppRouter.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Contact from './Pages/Contact';
import LogInForm from './Pages/RegisterAndLogin/LogIn';

const AppRouter = () => (
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/login" component={LogInForm} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
);
export default AppRouter;
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HeaderNotLoggedIn from './Headers/HeaderNotLoggedIn';
import HeaderLoggedIn from './Headers/HeaderLoggedIn';

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.isLoggedOn = this.isLoggedOn.bind(this);
    }

    isLoggedOn() {
        return localStorage.getItem('user');
    }

    render() {
        const header = this.isLoggedOn() ? <HeaderLoggedIn /> : <HeaderNotLoggedIn />;
        return <div>{header}</div>;
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Quite new to react, is there anything I'm missing here?

Why does the app only load correctly on page refresh?

Comment: Does the console say anything? Is there a problem on one route or on all routes?

Comment: No console errors

Comment: The conditional `ReactDOM.render` is a little suspect. Generally you want to handle conditional rendering inside of React itself. The root should be attached even if your cordova stuff isn't setup. It's kind of hard to tell though since I can't run your code.

Comment: @BrooksLybrand that's what I'm seeing, if I put an alert() inside startApp() it doesn't get fired until I reload the page - can I force the app load from inside react when the app starts?

Comment: Yes. I think the easiest solution would be to call `setupAltIntent ` in `componentDidMount` of `App`, and have it a `setState` when it's done. Then conditionally render everything inside of `App` based on the value of the components states. There are multiple ways to tackle this, but that should get you started. I write a lot of render methods that look like `render () { data ? <Child data={data} /> : null }`

Comment: @BrooksLybrand can you write that up as an answer with an example using my code? happy to accept if we can get it working - new to React router and it's taking some getting my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a way to to solve your exact problem, because there are a lot of components, logic, and connections I don't have access to, and so I have to make guesses about. I assume that `setupAltIntent` returns a promise (though it doesn't totally matter if it does something else). In `App` I set it up to conditionally render `Header` once the data has been loaded into the state, which happens when `setState` is called after the promise is resolved.

Hopefully this gets you far enough to figure out what exactly you need for your own solution.

Link to my solution:

[image: Edit Initial page load empty - Solution]